# R ggplot2/ezPlot: Plotting 3x3 RM ANOVA design per quantile of covariate with error bars

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

First of all, my data:

http://www.pastebin.ca/2599202 (I hope this is not too inconvenient, because I fail creating good fitting example data)

What I basically need, is a plot like the one I did [here](http://abload.de/img/rplotm1u05.png).

I plotted the repeated measures factor `time`(x-axis, 3 levels) against `ias` (continuous dependent variable) for my 3 experimental groups. I did this 4 times (for each quantile of my trait-measure `MIHT`, `miht.binned`, .25 - 1.00).

I have to admit I am not really an R professional and the `ggplot2` manual simply is an overkill for me. I created the plot with `ezPlot` (from `ezANOVA`) and only managed to do a bit layout tweaking with `ggplot2`:

```
PlotIAS = ezPlot(                               
      data = MyData
      , dv = .(ias)
      , wid = .(id)
      , between = .(GROUP, miht.binned)
      , within = .(time)
      , x = .(time)
      , split = .(GROUP)
      , col   = .(miht.binned)
      , x_lab = 'time of measurement'
      , y_lab = 'IAS Score (Mean)'
      #, do_bars = FALSE
      , type = 3
    )


    PlotIAS = PlotIAS +  
      theme(
        panel.grid.major.y = element_line(colour = "gray80", size = NULL, linetype = NULL,  
                                          lineend = NULL)
        ,panel.grid.minor.y = element_line(colour = "gray90", size = NULL, linetype = NULL,
                                           lineend = NULL)
        ,panel.grid.major.x = element_blank()           
        ,panel.grid.minor.x = element_blank()
        ,legend.background = element_rect(fill = NULL, colour = "black") 

        ,panel.background = element_rect(fill = "white", colour = "white", size = NULL, 
                                         linetype = NULL)
      )

print(PlotIAS)
```

I did'nt find any information about these error bars ezPlot creates. They seem to be the same for each point and length can be arbitrarily redifined with `bar_size =`. I just need to have error bars with SE or CI. I don't know if it is possible to add these in my ezPlot-based code (and how?) or if one has to create a complete new ggplot object for that (which is an quite an overcharge for me...). Help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this comes close to what you want:

```
ggplot(MyData, aes(x=time, y=ias, colour=GROUP, group=GROUP, 
                   linetype=GROUP, shape=GROUP)) + 
  facet_grid(~miht.binned) +
  stat_summary(fun.data="mean_cl_boot", geom="errorbar", conf.int=90) + 
    #alternatives:
    #stat_summary(fun.data="mean_cl_normal", geom="errorbar") + 
    #stat_summary(fun.data="mean_sdl", geom="errorbar") + 
  stat_summary(fun.y="mean", geom="point", size=2) + 
  stat_summary(fun.y="mean", geom="line") + 
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

See `?mean_cl_boot` etc for more info on where these error bars come from. `conf.int` is the CI-level. Also, having all three of colour, linetype AND shape mapped to GROUP seems like overkill. You could probably do without linetype and shape.

Let me add that

```
ggplot(MyData, aes(x=time, y=ias, fill=GROUP)) + facet_grid(~miht.binned) +
  geom_boxplot() + theme_bw()
```

[image]

may actually be a plot that's easier to read (no crossing/overlapping lines) while at the same time retaining more of the data's characteristics (min/max, outliers).

Comment: Thanks. The line with "mean_cl_boot" doesn't work, error as follows, but the other 2 work well. Did I get it right, that the first is a bootstrapping procedure, second normal CI and last SD? Your other suggestion is a good addition, but I prefer the first. Your hint with group overkill is appropriate I thin. Thanks! Error in quantile.default(z, c((1 - conf.int)/2, (1 + conf.int)/2)) : 
  'probs' outside [0,1]
Error in if (nrow(layer_data) == 0) return() : argument is of length zero

Comment: You're right about the way those error bars are calculated. I don't have the data at hand right now to follow up on the error you're getting.